# Unable to install mysql server_audit plugin on windows

Tags: mysql, plugins

I am trying to install mysql server audit plugin on windows 7. I am using following command to install the plugin

INSTALL PLUGIN server_audit SONAME 'server_audit.dll';

but I am getting following error,

mysql> INSTALL PLUGIN server_audit SONAME 'server_audit.dll';
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Serv
er 5.5\lib\plugin\server_audit.dll' (errno: 127 The specified procedure could no
t be found.)

I am not getting where I am going wrong. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error message mean the `dll` file doesn't exist, so you need to make sure `server_audit.dll` exist on `[mysql_dir]\lib`.